# android lagging fragment transition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, animation

Basicly I have an app with a single activity and 5 fragments. Since the creation of the fragment layout takes up to a second, I change my method in a way that it doesn't recreate the fragments and just hides and shows them.

```
private void openFragment(int index)
{
    if(index == activeFragment)
    {
        return;
    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //Set animations
    if(activeFragment < index)
    {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    } else {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    //Hide old Fragment
    if (Fragments.get(activeFragment).isAdded())
    {
        ft.hide(Fragments.get(activeFragment));
        Fragments.get(activeFragment).getView().setTranslationZ(0);
    }

    //Add/Show new Fragment
    if (Fragments.get(index).isAdded()) 
    { // if the fragment is already in container
        ft.show(Fragments.get(index));
        Fragments.get(index).getView().setTranslationZ(1f);
    } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, Fragments.get(index), Integer.toString(index));
    }

    // Commit changes
    ft.commit();
}
```

The problem is that the animation stutters, even if I change to a fragment with only one `RecyclerView` and 10 items in it. It also takes a long time to load if I start the fragment for the first time, even if I create the fragment in the `OnCreate` method (so its taking so long, because it is adding the fragment into the fragment container? It takes half a second for the container with only the `RecyclerView`). However if I don't set any transition, the fragments will show up immediately with just a small delay (maybe 30ms, not even worth mentioning). Why is the main thread so overwhelmed with the animation, it doesn't have to create any view, just fading away one fragment and fading another in.

How can I handle fragments, so that I can transition between them smoothly, while keeping the delay as low as possible? I use a `BottomNavigationView` to navigate through the fragments, so it has to open immediently, that's why I save the fragments.

Comment: Do you experience the same if you use navigation approach ?

See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph

I see same as you, it may be the fact that the transition animation "collides" with the setup navigaion performed when recyclerview is created.

RG

Comment: @RoarGrønmo It's not only with recycleviews, webviews are 10x worse. If you open the fragment with the webview the first time, it laggs for 0.3 seconds of the animation and the next time it only laggs for 0.15 seconds. I didnt tried it with navigation component, cause if I remove the animations, it doesn't look laggy. In fact the fragments swap nearly instantly, which is weird. It looks much faster without animations.

Comment: I ended up using a contentloadingprogressbar actually where I had the problem. It didn't solve the root cause, but it is fair for now.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue even with Navigation component. Had to use a handler to delay adding data to the recyclerview adapter by 300ms and it worked.

Comment: But If there is a ScrollView or WebView it is still not smooth. The best way I found was to remove transitions completely. That way there are no laggy transitions and the new fragment takes maybe 50-100ms to open which is way better then the stuttering transition.